# Can the Canon 600D take images one stop up & down for creating an HDR image?

Tags: canon, hdr, canon-600d, bracketing

I can see that Canon 600D [can't take multiple exposures](http://kbsupport.cusa.canon.com/system/selfservice.controller?CONFIGURATION=1011&PARTITION_ID=1&secureFlag=false&TIMEZONE_OFFSET=&CMD=VIEW_ARTICLE&ARTICLE_ID=54005), but my 600D has a menu option that states...

```
C.Fn : Exposure
Exposure level increments
0: 1/3 stop
1: 1/2 stop
```

I'd like to take several images to create an HDR image - is this possible on the 600D?

Answer (score 7):

Yes, it can - the option you're after is "auto exposure bracketing" (AEB), which can most easily be configured from the quick menu - select the meter (the -3 to +3 scale), press "SET", then turn the control wheel. At this point, the little indicator marker should split into three, which will mean that the next three shots the camera takes will have normal exposure, under exposure and over exposure, with the difference in exposure being selectable. For more details, see page 105 the [manual](http://gdlp01.c-wss.com/gds/7/0300008087/03/EOS_600D_Instruction_Manual_EN.pdf). Note that this is more flexible than just plus or minus one stop - you can do other values from 1/3 of a stop to 2 stops (or maybe more - 2 stops is the limit on the 550D) if you want to.

The custom function you found is unrelated to this - that allows you to select whether you get 1/2 or 1/3 stop increments when changing shutter speed or aperture.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to Philip Kendall's answer, the document you've found advising that the Canon 600D can't take multiple exposures, is referring to the ability to shoot more than one exposure and combine them in camera to produce a single image.

For info on that technique see this question [How can multiple exposure be achieved with a digital camera?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/20490/how-can-multiple-exposure-be-achieved-with-a-digital-camera) and  Wikipeida [Multiple exposure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_exposure).

Answer (score 0):

You can simulate multiple exposures in post-processing.

The custom setting you found is not for taking brackets of shots, it's simply for setting whether you want 1/2 stops or 1/3 stops as the units for partial-stop settings on the camera.

And yes, the 600D can perform autobracketing.  You cannot, however, change the number of shots you can get in a set (3), and you can only adjust the range of the exposure covered up to 3EV in both directions (i.e., a 6EV range) with AEB.  If you need to cover a larger range, you'll have to do it manually.  The 600D also cannot do the HDR processing in-camera.  You will have to do the HDR merging and tonemapping in post on the computer.

To use bracketing on the 600D, you have to set it in the camera menus (see [pages 105-106 of the manual](http://gdlp01.c-wss.com/gds/0/0300004720/02/eosrt3i-eos600d-im2-c-en.pdf#page=105)), and then take all the frames (i.e., press the shutter button three times, or use burst mode to take the three frames).  You will not get the full bracketed set with a single shutter button push, unless you're using [the Magic Lantern firmware add-on](http://www.magiclantern.fm/) and its HDR Bracketing feature, also allows for more than 3 frames to be shot in a bracketed set.